# How to create new strings from the result of a string split?

Tags: java, string, split

I have to split a string containing a full name and need to create new first name and last name strings.  I used this to split the full name based on the space between names:

```
  String fullName = "John Doe";
       String[] result = fullName.split(" ");
       for(String token:result)
            System.out.println(token);
```

I get the correct output, "John" and "Doe".  How do I now use that to create

```
String firstName = "John";
String lastName = "Doe";
```

Thanks

Comment: and your language is...Java?

Comment: Yes, it's JAVA. Sorry, first time posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String fullName = "John Doe";
String[] result = fullName.split(" ");
String firstName=result[0];
String lastName=result[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String fullName = "John Doe";
    String firstName=fullName.substring(0,fullName.indexOf(" "));
    String lastName=fullName.substring(fullName.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
```